# Чтение с конца файла си

Tags: c, файлы

Здравствуйте. Буду краток. Вопрос заключается в том как наиболее эффективно произвести чтение последней строки из файла в си, чтобы не прогонять fscanf ом все строки файла а сразу считать последнюю строку? Заранее спасибо

Comment: fseek . . . . .

Comment: tail же! ну и исходники :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если размер файла таков, что вариант "прогонять fscanf ом все строки файла" является чересчур расточительным, то остается только

1. Открыть файл в бинарном режиме<sup>1</sup>
2. Завести буфер из `N` байтов
3. В цикле вызовами `fseek(..., -(i * N), SEEK_END)` (или `fseek(..., -N, SEEK_CUR)`) постепенно отступать назад от конца файла с шагом `N`
4. Считывать из файла очередную порцию из `N` байтов в буфер
5. Проверять буфер на предмет наличия в нем платформенно-зависимого<sup>2</sup> маркера конца строки

Таким образом вы сумеете найти ту позицию в файле, с которой начинается последняя строка и затем считать эту строку. Разумеется, можно сразу использовать переаллоцируемый буфер и постоянно накапливать читаемые в процессе поиска данные, ибо они являются частью искомой строки.

В качестве побочного замечания можно добавить, что формально стандартная библиотека С не обязана поддерживать позиционирование от конца файла (`SEEK_END`), т.е. с формально-абстрактной точки зрения "прогонять fscanf ом все строки файла" является единственным решением. Непонятно только, при чем здесь именно `fscanf`, а не более уместный `fgets`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Стандартная библиотека С не поддерживает произвольного позиционирования в текстовых потоках

<sup>2</sup> Так как файл открыт в бинарном режиме, трансляции платформенно-зависимого маркера конца строки в символ `\n` происходить не будет

Comment: *man mmap* и не надо всякой фигни с буферами.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам понадобятся замечательные ф-ции `fseek ()` и `ftell ()`. Если вкратце, то для перехода в конец файла нужна команда

```
 fseek (fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
```

Но, правда, кое-где такой код может и не работать... Особенно, если ваша система не потомок UNIX.

Comment: Это хорошо. А последнюю строку-то как прочитать?

Comment: идешь от конца файла по байтам до символа новой стоки - иначе никак) Типа `while (getc (fp) != '\n") fseek (fp, -2L, SEEK_CUR);` - это прикидка на глаз

Comment: Для текстового потока позиционирование может дать не верный результат. А для бинарного режима позиция 0 в сочетании с SEEK_END приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: Не понадобятся, если делать чуть умнее.